# Ajax request send property path

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to send data to server.

My Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: config.api.url,
  type: config.api.method,
  contentType: config.api.contentType, // application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
  dataType: config.api.dataType,       // JSON
  data: config.api.dataType === 'GET' ? {} : JSON.parse(tmp),
  headers: config.api.headers,
  success: (response) => { onSuccess(response); },
  error: (error) => { onError(error); }
});
```

My data:

```
{
  sort: { name: 1 }
}
// I set name property by sort['name'] = 1; at js
```

But the server received:

```
{ 'sort[name]': 1 }
```

My nodejs server code:

```
exampleData = (req, res) => {
  var sort = req.body.sort;
  console.log(sort);       // undefined
  console.log(req.body);   // { ..., 'sort[name]': 1 }
}
```

Chrome Form Data:

[image: Chrome Form Data]

So, I can't read object correctly like an object sent from ajax request, something went wrong?

How can I fix it?

Comment: What does the server code look like?

Comment: Hi @Musa I updated my question, please see the change, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are using express.js. If yes then you need body parser middleware.

```
var app = require('express')(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, i tried to do that in my server: `const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: 1024*1024*20, type: 'application/json' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// app.use(express.bodyParser({limit: '50mb'}));`

Comment: Why would you use a JSON parser to parse `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Thank @Musa, I change `contentType` to `application/json` and it work!

Comment: You need to send data in string JSON format with contentType as 'application/json'. Hope this helps.